# Can anyone please explain me whats happening here : "protected" modifier in java

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

One thing I have learnt is `private` in java doesn't really mean same thing as that in C++. `private` in java is class-based, not object-based.
i.e I can access another objects private member directly using "object dot notation" **provided that** I do so within the class of that object.

However, `protected` is not so clear. 
We will have to consider two packages here : `pack1` and `pack2`
We declare classes `Alpha` and `Beta` in `pack1` package
and declare `AlphaSub` which extends `Alpha` from `pack1` , and `Gamma` **which also extends from `Alpha`** in `pack2` package.
!

[image]

Here is the class code, I have only included classes relevant to the issue here : `Alpha`,  `AlphaSub` and `Gamma`

```
package pack1;

public class Alpha{
  private int alphaPrivate;
  public int alphaPublic;
  protected int alphaProtected;
  int alphaPP;

  protected int alphaProtected(){
    return 1;
  }
  private int alphaPrivate(){
    return 1;
  }
}

package pack2;

import pack1.Alpha;
public class AlphaSub extends Alpha{
    int alphasubPP;
    private int alphasubPrivate;
    protected int alphasubProtected;
    public int alphasubPublic;

    public void meth() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
        new AlphaSub().alphaProtected(); //OK
        new Gamma().alphaProtected(); /*COMPILE ERROR. */

    }
}
```

So apparently even though both AlphaSub and Gamma inherits `alphaProtected()` from `Alpha` , one cannot invoke Gamma's inherited `alphaProtected()` from AlphaSub .. 
If this is the case that protected method of a class can only be called from within that class, wouldn't invocation of `clone` [inherited by every class from `Object` class] from another class be impossible ??

Someone can please clarify ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, what's the difference between public, default, protected, and private?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)

Answer (score 1):

What you experienced is covered in [JLS 6.6.2.1.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.1):

> 6.6.2.1. Access to a protected Member
>
> Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is
>   permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.
>
> In addition, if Id denotes an instance field or instance method, then:
>
> - If the access is by a qualified name Q.Id or a method reference expression Q :: Id (§15.13), where Q is an ExpressionName, then the
>     access is permitted if and only if the type of the expression Q is S
>     or a subclass of S.
> - If the access is by a field access expression E.Id, or a method invocation expression E.Id(...), or a method reference expression E ::
>     Id, where E is a Primary expression (§15.8), then the access is
>     permitted if and only if the type of E is S or a subclass of S.
> - If the access is by a method reference expression T :: Id, where T is a ReferenceType, then the access is permitted if and only if the
>     type T is S or a subclass of S.

And you are correct, if you replace `new Gamma().alphaProtected();` with `new Gamma().clone();`, you'll get the same compilation error.

Comment: yet we should be able to invoke `new Gamma().clone` from outside `Gamma` class's body, no ? otherwise what significant purpose will the `clone` method serve for Gamma class ? 
I think `clone` method would have to be redefined in `Gamma` for it to be invoked from outside `Gamma`, no ?? please clarify\

Comment: oh yes , it actually does. Just overrode the protected method in Gamma and it works ! 
funny how there's so much more to things than whats simply stated in tutorial docs